# Enable Disable specific date from input type=date when date stored in DB

Tags: php, input

I have a form to assign my employee work by date.

```
 <?php //for db connection
   include '../../database/dbconnect.php';
 ?>


 <form method="post" action="">
    <select name="fname">
        <option></option>
        <option>Masud</option>
        <option>Sharmin</option>
        <option>Ahsan</option>
        <option>Nobel</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date" name="assign_date">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ASSIGN">
  </form>
```

all fname option is stored in assign_roster table and has column ros_day which has specific date like 2018-11-10.

Now if i select Masud then date 2018-11-10 should be disable from input date, coz i dont want to assign same person in same day.

How can i do this ? Please Help :-)

Comment: you must use javascript to manage that.

Comment: do you have any link to do that using js? i use some js but i can not get data from database table assign_roster and column ros_day

Answer (score -1):

if you're using database so you can add two columns in your users table first one name it 'check' for example values will be 0 or 1 , so when option is selected 'check' will be =1 and add the date in the second column added so when you list your options next time you'll have just availabe dates and users.

Comment: do you have any link to do that, i mean any tutorial link